# Disabling firebase screen reporting (and automatic collection if available)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I decided to intergrate firebase analytic in to the mobile application. So far it works very well.

Now I want to disable the automatic screen reporting, since our team already has another solution for that and it will also save some money on the bigquery service as well.

I did some research on its git and the internet. So far, I cannot find anything usable. Anyone here can help me ? Thank you.

ref: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/370